# How to fix these IOErrors when creating a thumbnail from a filepath in PIL (Python Imaging Library)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ioerror

I am trying to make a simple function in python that can take in a filepath and an outputfilepath, and then make a 64x64 thumbnail for the image found at filepath and save the thumbnail to outputfilepath. Here is my entire code:

```
def create_thumbnail2(filepath, outputpath):
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        print "Input file path for create_thumbnail doesn't exist. Returning None"
        return None

    try:
        size = 64, 64 #Will be making a 64x64 thumbnail                                                                                           
        im = Image.open(filepath)
        print "image successfully opened"
        im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        print "made thumbnail"
        im.save(outputpath, "PNG") #Save image as a PNG                                                                                           
        return outputpath
    except IOError:
        print "I/O error"
        return None

print "TEST 1"
filep = "test_images/cat1.jpg"
print create_thumbnail2(filep, "test_images/cat1_thumbnail.png")

print "\nTEST 2"
filep = "test_images/cat2.jpg"
print create_thumbnail2(filep, "test_images/cat2_thumbnail.png")
```

The problem is that this code will work fine for some images, but will raise an IOError on the line where I call "im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)". Here is the output of the above program.

```
TEST 1
image successfully opened
I/O error
None

TEST 2
image successfully opened
made thumbnail
test_images/cat2_thumbnail.png
```

You'll notice that in the first test, the an I/O Error is thrown after the image is opened but before a thumbnail is created. In the second test no error is thrown, and the thumbnail is actually successfully saved to the outputpath. No matter what order I call the two different tests in, or if I comment one out and run the other one alone, the result is always TEST 1 failing and TEST 2 succeeding. Both cat1.jpg and cat2.jpg seem to be valid JPEG images, I can't really find anything different between them besides the file names and the actual picture content.

In case anyone wants to try it with my images, I downloaded cat1 from here: http://dellone2one.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/angry_wet_cat.jpg

and I downloaded cat2 from here: http://cvcl.mit.edu/hybrid/cat2.jpg

EDITED TO ADD THE FULL TRACEBACK WITHOUT THE HANDLING:
Here is the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_utils.py", line 75, in <module>
    print create_thumbnail2(filep, "test_images/cat1_thumbnail.png")
  File "image_utils.py", line 66, in create_thumbnail2
    im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
  File "/Users/dylan/arcode/python/arcode/PIL/Image.py", line 1559, in thumbnail
    self.load()
  File "/Users/dylan/arcode/python/arcode/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 189, in load
    d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, d, a, self.decoderconfig)
  File "/Users/dylan/arcode/python/arcode/PIL/Image.py", line 385, in _getdecoder
    raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
IOError: decoder jpeg not available
```

Comment: It would help if you removed your exception handling and posted the full traceback.

Comment: Seems like its a problem with my version of PIL. Would you concur?

Answer (score 1):

My installation of PIL does the same. (PIL 1.1.7, Py 2.6, OSX 10.6)

EDIT:
Ah - the installation on a different OSX machine works. I know there are issues building PIL with JPG support on OSX, but I can't recall what the source of each of the two installations was, so I can't tell you how to fix it.

EDIT 2: 
My best recollection is that building PIL with something like the instructions [here](http://passingcuriosity.com/2009/installing-pil-on-mac-os-x-leopard/) yielded the working installation. The build and install commands had to be run sudo, and three invocations of gcc had to be manually modified to remove the "-arch ppc" option and re-run.

And here's [another route](http://bradmontgomery.blogspot.com/2010/02/building-pil-on-os-x-snow-leopard.html) to building PIL.

Comment: hmm, ok. I am pretty sure that I just installed mine from MacPorts

Comment: So the installation on the other OSX, is that also PIL 1.1.7, Py 2.6, OSX 10.6?

Comment: PIL-1.1.7-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg, but running on OSX 10.6. I think I built it myself using the instructions here: http://passingcuriosity.com/2009/installing-pil-on-mac-os-x-leopard/